Proving that if $A \Delta B \subseteq A$ then $B \subseteq A$
In one of the answers to this question, a user suggested using the fact that $A \Delta B = (A \cap B^C) \cup (B \cap A^C) \subseteq A$ implies $B \cap A^C = \emptyset$. Why is that? $(A \cap B^C) \cup (B \cap A^C) \subseteq A$ means either $A \cap B^C \subseteq A$ or $B \cap A^C \subseteq A$ or both $(A \cap B^C) \subseteq A$ and $(B \cap A^C) \subseteq A$, but they are not required to be both subsets of $A$. Doesn't $B \cap A^C = \emptyset$ only follow if the latter thing is true? Or am I misunderstanding what the union operator means?

Yeah, they are both required to be subsets of $A$. If $C\cup D\subseteq A$ then both $C$ and $D$ are subsets of $A$. In your case, both $A\cap B^c$ and $B\cap A^c$ are subsets of $A$.

@alvoi Oh I think I can see why. $C \cup D \subseteq A$ means $\forall x (x \in C \lor x \in D \implies x \in A)$. So any element that is either in $C$ or in $D$ must be in $A$, i.e. all elements of $C$ and all elements of $D$ must be in $A$.

Sometimes a Venn diagram maybe good to see. Try to sketch out then I think is obvious, because you want some elements lying outside $A$ (in $B\cap A^C$) to be in $A$, then it must be empty.
